If a I rent a car in Zurich, Switzerland, can I return the car in Lauterbrunnen?
4 adults are landing in Zurich, renting a car and traveling to Germany, then Austria and back to Switzerland, staying in Wengen, which is a no-car city, so we want to return our car in Lauterbrunnen. Can we do this?

At slightly more than 1000 inhabitants, calling Wengen a city is a bit of a stretch.

being car dependent.... in europe?

@Rainb Depending on where you visit and what you want to do, also in Europe a car can be a major time-saver.  Even in Switzerland, some places only get buses a couple of times per day and making day hikes without a car offers only limited possibilities.  For visiting cities a car is a hinder, but for exploring rural areas it offers much greater flexibility and time savings compared to public transportation.  Wengen, however, is one of the top tourist destinations in the Alps and one where one is much better off without a car (parking in Lauterbrunnen, like Täsch, is not fun).

Return it in Zurich before going to Wengen and take the train from Zurich to Lauterbrunnen: cheaper, faster, more relaxing and scenic.

@Gerrit The OP is probably American. In America, the term "city" simply means the administrative unit where you live, even if it's a tiny hamlet. That's why forms on the web often ask for the "city" of your address as a mandatory field.

There are places in Europe which can not be visited without the use of a car, even more so if one of the party is not able to walk longer distances. And more so if you have a lot of luggage. So yes, car dependent is reality also in Europe.

@Rainb ??  Europe is the, obviously, paradise of cars.  Your comment would be something like saying "what? visit the Himalayas to see mountains?" the overwhelming reason people travel to Europe is to experience the universe of Ferrari, Porsche, autobahn, scenery, engineering wonders etc.

OP, are you aware you can Park your car in Lauterbrunnen ?

@Rainb you may no have heard of all the strikes in all kinds of public transport in Germany lately. Most of the conflicts are finally solved, but they had become so long and unpredictable that I rented a car for my last vacation trip. And in the future, I plan to check the end date of the relevant bargaining agreements and rent a car every time that my trip date is close to that date.

No, you can't, because as far as I can tell there are zero rental car agencies in Lauterbrunnen.
Your options are:

Return your car in Interlaken, which is only a few train stops away
Ditch the rental car and travel by train, which is cheaper, faster (on many routes), avoids the need for winter driving on twisty roads that may get closed at short notice, lets you fully appreciate the great views, and is extremely punctual in Switzerland (but less so in Germany, alas).  You're going to need to board a train for the final stretch to Wengen anyway.


And of course option 3. Change your plans to visit a car-friendly town instead.

@JonathanReez or keep the car while you're in Wengen and pay for parking in Lauterbrunnen or Grindelwald.  If there is a one-way rental fee it could well be more than the cost of parking for a week.

@StuartF i think the train suggestion makes sense, they would either need to take the train from Interlaken to Wengen anyway (after returning the car since there are no agencies in Lauterbrunnen), take the train from Lauterbrunnen from Wengen (if there were agencies) or take the train from Zurich to Wengen. Zurich to Lauterbrunnen is a 9 hour bicycle ride so not feasible with luggages (and frankly exhausting anyway). The fact that they want to return the car in Lauterbrunnen to go to Wengen instead of searching for a parking probably means that it's not needed for their trip in Switzerland

The train suggestion would make sense if it were just about going from Zurich to Wengen. But it sounds OP has a full trip planned, visiting places (I am assuming multiple) in Germany and Austria. For such a trip "take a train" simply isn't a drop-in replacement for a car. I would rather suggest parking in Lauterbrunnen and returning your car back in Zurich.

@xLeitix The OP has not shared their itinerary, but there are plenty of cross-border services from Switzerland to both Germany and Austria.

@lambshaanxy "To Austria", yes. "To a couple of specific places in Austria at reasonably predefined times" - good luck. Sure, it's possible to book a nice round-trip via train (actually planning something like that myself for summer), but you need to plan your trip around train availability/schedules and prepare for somewhat more leisurely travelling. That's why I said it's not a drop-in replacement - if OP goes for your suggestion they probably need to adapt a lot of the rest of their itinerary as well.

@xLeitix Sure, but OP already has to take a train, so might as well review the plans and see which bits make sense to go by car and which bits don't.

@xLeitix OP wants to ditch their car, so clearly doesn't need it anymore after the Wengen visit.  That makes the advice to ditch the car a little earlier perfectly sound.  Drive Zurich - Germany - Austria - Zurich, return rental car, and do the Wengen part of the trip entirely by train.

Option (1), yes. It's option (2) I am sceptical about.

If you can comfortably carry your luggage over short distances, I would even suggest returning your car at Zurich again (in addition to @lambshaanxy's answer), and then use the train right from there. Many rental agencies give you a discount when returning at the original location.

@JonathanReez car friendly towns are usually people un-friendly towns. They rarely make for good holiday destinations. That we have no cars in Wengen is what makes it such an agreeable place.

@StuartF Wengen is famously a car-free region only accessible by train so it's kind of bizarre to take a recommendation "don't use car to go to car-free region" as some kind of rant, especially when mentioned train will be necessary to reach the place in any case.

Some rental companies offer the option to leave the car in a predetermined location, and they will then pick it up from there. It’s far from all rental companies that offer this (though I know Europcar do, or at least used to), and it’s usually quite steep, but the absence of a car rental agent in Lauterbrunnen may not be an absolute hindrance.
